# how did mllib calculate gradient

Tags: apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib, gradient-descent

Need an mllib expert to help explain the linear regression code. In [`LeastSquaresGradient.compute`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/Gradient.scala#L279)

```
override def compute(
    data: Vector,
    label: Double,
    weights: Vector,
    cumGradient: Vector): Double = {
  val diff = dot(data, weights) - label
  axpy(diff, data, cumGradient)
  diff * diff / 2.0
}
```

cumGradient is computed using axpy, which is simply y += a * x, or here
cumGradient += diff * data

I thought for a long time but can make the connection to the gradient calculation as defined in the gradient descent documentation. In theory the gradient is the slope of the loss against delta in one particular weighting parameter. I don't see anything in this axpy implementation that remotely resemble that.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: I believe this question belongs on [stats.stackexchange.com](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really a programming question but to give you some idea what is going on cost function for least square regression is defined as

[image]

where theta is weights vector.

Partial derivatives of the above cost function are:

[image]

and if computed over all theta:

[image]

It should be obvious that above is equivalent to `cumGradient += diff * data` computed for all data points and to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Definition)

> in a rectangular coordinate system, the gradient is the vector field whose components are the partial derivatives of f

Comment: Excellent. My confusion was not seeing that x, and y are both Vectors with the features as elements. Now the code does perfectly match the math.